# How to make a super class whose member function becomes private in the child

Tags: java

I have define super class who's member variables are private and functions are public. I want that super class' methods to be accessible in the child class, but not from the outside of that class.

In other words, super class' methods become private in the child class so that they can not be accessed from outside of the class. Is this behavior possible or not?

Comment: declare the methods of your superclass as `protected`

Comment: You cannot reduce visibility in a subclass. This is part of the design of the Java language, as you can find by reading the JLS or trying it in any IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for the `protected` modifier. `protected` methods can be accessed from classes in the same package and extending classes.

Another way is the inversion of control using the template method pattern: The base class defines behavior in a non-abstract method using abstract methods the child classes have to overwrite - so that the child classes only have to extend the specific parts and don't have to care about the rest.

Answer (score 0):

technically java doen't have a modifier for this use case but protected make you come closer but allow to access within package.